# Part specification error only in LogPlot

Tags: list-manipulation

I've a problem. I defined a simple list and a function like below:

```
lst := {5, 10, 20}
f[m_] := lst[[Floor[m/10]]];
```

and drew a plot

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 10, 38}]
```

which works fine.
But when calling LogPlot

```
LogPlot[f[x], {x, 10, 38}]
```

the following error appears before the plot

```
Part::pspec: "Part specification Floor[x/10] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers"
```

Can anyone suggest me what's going on and how to deal with this error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate, specifically the issue of `Plot` first attempting a symbolic evaluation of the function.  Can anyone find it?

Comment: Yeah I would also like to now if that symbolic manipulation of `LogPlot` can be turned off somehow, so that I can plot a function without having to specify the function arguments as done in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LogPlot[]` is trying to symbolically manipulate your `f[]`, and the `Part[]` function fails at that.

You may try to specify that your function should be evaluated only for numerical input, but not symbolically:

```
lst := {5, 10, 20}
f[m_?NumericQ] := lst[[Floor[m/10]]];
LogPlot[f[x], {x, 10, 38}]
```